# Google Sheets get.range syntax if the range is formed partly from a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a counter in cell `F26` that starts with `0` and grows by one every time a new row with a text is added below it. First time the script executes, it would copy the values of the formulas in `F27:G27` to `F27:G27` (and add the `0` from the counter and thus be in row `27`). Next time it executes it would take the value from the `F26`, that is now `1`, and add it to the row number `27` so making the next execution `F28:G28` to `F28:G28` and so on.

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F27:G27').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('G27'));
  spreadsheet.getRange('F27:G27').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 
  spreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

What would be the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Algorithmically, here are the steps you need to follow:

1. Get the current **counter** from cell `F26`:

   `var counter = sheet.getRange('F26').getValue();`
2. Use [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and set as `row` the **starting row** `27` **plus** the current value of `counter`:

   `var range = sheet.getRange(27+counter,6,1,2);`
3. Copy only the contents/values:

   `range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true});`
4. **Increment** the counter by `1`:

   `sheet.getRange('F26').setValue(sheet.getRange('F26').getValue()+1);`

---

### Snippet:

```
function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet4'); // change that to your sheet name
  var counter = sheet.getRange('F26').getValue(); // get the counter
  var range = sheet.getRange(27+counter,6,1,2); // start from 27 plus counter
  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true}); // copy the values
  sheet.getRange('F26').setValue(sheet.getRange('F26').getValue()+1); // increase F26 by 1
};
```